# Problems with DevPartner

Tags: c++, visual-c++, devpartner

I have installed DevPartner and I am using visual studio 2010.

However, when I launch 'Start with coverage analysis', nothing happens.

In the videos, they show that in the under Options->DevPartner->Code review, there should be a list of projects. But I do not see such list.

It will be great if you could please help me with it.

Many thanks.

Chintan

Comment: Run standalone DevPartner and open you project executable from it.

Answer (score 0):

Coverage analysis ans Code review are 2 separate products in the Devpartner Suite.

Coverage Analysis is to used to determine which lines of code are executed in a run of your project. You can also merge several runs to get an overall idea of how much code you have exercised. Coverage analysis works for both Native (C, C++) and managed languages.

When you launch your application with coverage analysis you will only see a small toolbar appear that allows you to take snapshots or stop recording coverage information. After your program exits a final session will be collected and displaying in Visual Studio. Unless something is wrong with your license. Another problem would be when launching Visual Studio and opening your project you may see an error unable similar to Devpartner start session control service.

Code Review is used as static analysis of Managed (.Net) code. It does not run your project but analysis the code in your projects and determines if any of that code violates the rule set you selected to run against.